# How to render a YUI datatable?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

Following [the documentation of the YUI DataTable control](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/) i've inferred the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        // Create a new YUI instance and populate it with the required modules.
        YUI().use('datatable', function (Y) {
            // Columns must match data object property names
            var data = [
                { id: "ga-3475", name: "gadget",   price: "$6.99", cost: "$5.99" },
                { id: "sp-9980", name: "sprocket", price: "$3.75", cost: "$3.25" },
                { id: "wi-0650", name: "widget",   price: "$4.25", cost: "$3.75" }
            ];

            var table = new Y.DataTable({
                columns: ["id", "name", "price"],
                data: data,

                // Optionally configure your table with a caption
                caption: "My first DataTable!",

                // and/or a summary (table attribute)
                summary: "Example DataTable showing basic instantiation configuration"
            });
            table.render("#example");
        });
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The insulting thing is that the documentation says:

> This code produces this table:
>
> [image]

except that this code produces this table:

[image]

So obviously i'm missing something pretty fundamental about how to render a YUI data table. What is the correct way to render a YUI data table?

**Q.** How to render a YUI datatable?

---

[Another page](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-basic.html) mentions including a `<div>`, changing my `<BODY>` from empty to:

```
<BODY>
    <div class="example yui3-skin-sam">
        <div id="simple"></div>

        <div id="labels"></div>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

but does not change the look of the control.

Answer (score 2):

Add `class="yui3-skin-sam"` in body tag, table css is written corresponding to this class.

Answer (score 1):

Move the <script>s to the bottom of the <body>, or at least after the <div> that will contain the DataTable.  That will avoid a race condition where the scripts *may* be loaded before the DOM is set up.

render('#example') is telling the DataTable to render into an element with an id of 'example'  The markup sample you included has a div with a *class* of 'example', then two divs with ids 'simple' and 'labels'.  You need to make sure you're rendering inside a parent element with class yui3-skin-sam.  If you tell a YUI widget to render into an element it can't find, it falls back to rendering it inside the <body>.  You can fix this in a few ways:

- add the class to the <body> tag instead of a <div> (not a bad idea, but you should still fix the render target selector)
- use a render(*?*) target selector that matches an element on the page, such as render('.example'), render('#simple'), or render('#labels').

In any case, make sure your render target is inside an element with class="yui3-skin-sam"

Comment: i tried to make the changes i think i inferred from your notes. It didn't work. Can you post code with the changes you suggest?